# ログイン認証無しでデータベースからデータを読む事が可能なDBを教えて頂けないでしょうか?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

現在､FIREBASEのデータを実機で読むことが出来ません。
(シミュレータでは読めるのですがまだ色々調べないといけないと思うのですが)
データを読み込むだけなのでログイン認証などしないでDBを読みたいのですが､良いDBが有ったら教えて頂けないでしょうか?

`NET上のDBを使いたいのです`。
DROPBOX?

Comment: NET上のDBを使いたいのです

Comment: そういうのあるんですかね？普通、検索クエリのみ投げるにしても負荷やらなんやらあるので外部からゲストアカウントは使わせないと思いますが…。
(クエリ投げられまくったり負荷の高いクエリ投げられたらDB死ぬ)
ログインしない、…がイコール認証しないということだと、APIキーなども対象外ですか？いまいち何がしたいのか掴めないですがDBである必要性から見直したほうがいい気もします。(質問文ももう少し詰めた方がいい気も…)
個人的にはデータベースファイルをローカルにダウンロード、展開してRealmとかSQLiteとかで検索する感じがいいと思います。

Comment: 私もデータベースファイルをローカルにダウンロードして使いたいのですが、ここでいうところのデータベースファイルがwebにあると思うのですが ?

Comment: 確かにクエリ投げられぱなしだとDBがダウンしそうですが、firebaseは匿名認証というのもあるみたいです。使い方がわかりませんが。

Comment: @tamatw2020 1つ目としてファイルをWebに設置しローカルにダウンロード後に使用するというのは間違っていない認識ですが何か問題を感じますか？、2つ目として匿名認証とはいえIPと端末情報を用いて一時的なユーザ情報を取得します。その後uidを使用して接続するので全く認証しないわけではなかったと思います。この匿名のユーザ情報の発行は同一IPから短時間に複数のリクエストがあった場合に失敗します。

Comment: 有難う御座います。アプリの質問データを追加する時、WEB上にデータベースがあった方がアプリを変更しなくて良いというのが一番の理由です、ゲームの為にID,パスワードが必要なのはユーザーも面倒だと思いそんな使い買ってがよいデータベースがないかと質問しました。

Answer (score 1):

Swift(iOS)アプリの開発には詳しくないので扱えるか分かりませんが、例えば**SQLite**などでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

iOSで内部的にデータベースを使いたいのであれば、有名どころは

- [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) (ラッパーに[FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)や、[SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift)があります)
- [Realm](https://realm.io/jp/docs/swift/latest/) （Realmのラッパーが賢いので、SQLをほとんど意識せずに使えます）

等があると思います。
どちらのデータベースも実績が充分あるので余程特殊なデーターを扱わない限り大丈夫だと思います。